# Adding Speak Methods

Tags: php, class, methods, easyphp

How do I add a speak method to the Dog class below.
I am trying to give the dog the ability to bark.

```
<?php
class Dog
{
    private $dog_weight = 0;
    private $dog_breed = "no breed";
    private $dog_color = "no color";
    private $dog_name = "no name";



function display_properties()
{



    print "Dog weight is $this->dog_weight. Dog breed is $this->dog_breed.     Dog color is $this->dog_color.";


}
}
?>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87850/php-oop-example-using-animal-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're being downvoted because of the basic nature of the question, but essentially you'll simply need to:

- Create a public method on the class
- `echo` (or `print` as you have above) the content you want the Dog class to say

Check out the ["Defining Class Methods" section on this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762) for an easy overview.